# Move local file to SFTP Server in Workato

Tags: workato

I am new to Workato and want to create a recipe to automate task of moving a file from local folder to SFTP server in Workato?

I have created a connection to to local folder using On-prem Agent and SFTP server using username and password. However, I unable to create steps to copy file from a local folder to SFTP server.